# New variable in Alteryx without join

Tags: alteryx

So i've created a simple bit of analysis in alteryx, and I'm looking for a bit of advice.

I have a dataset of merchants and shoppers.  I pull out the total number of unique shoppers with a summarize node countdistinct(shoppers) - let's say it's 100.  Then, I create a table for the number of unique shoppers within each merchant, and that table looks something like this

Merchant | Unique Users

Merchant 1 | 76

Merchant 2 | 19

Merchant 3 | 97

Merchant 4 | 44

Merchant 5 | 55

...

I'd like to create a variable that will be [Number of Distinct Users]/countdistinct(shoppers).

I know that I could just append the value for countdistinct(shoppers) into a new third column in my table, but I'd prefer not to do that unless I have to.  Is there a way to save the single number from countdistinct(shoppers) as a value and simply divide directly by that without having to append or join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There currently is no way to do that in Alteryx.  While it feels wrong or wasteful, by including the calculated count distinct value on every record, Alteryx can process each record individually and then pass it down stream.

I have heard talk of creating something like a global variable that could be accessed or updated to handle the situation that you're describing, but the complexity of managing reads and writes from different parts of the workflow as well as any resulting slowdown from thread coordination always sideline the discussion.